# Extra information in URL redirecting from nolayout.aspx to 404 error page in sitecore website

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore

I just moved my nolayout.aspx to 404 error page inside config file, everything is working fine except the URL. After getting redirect to 404 URL has these extra information : 
404?item=%2fservices-and-solutions%2fbusiness-vision%2fit-without-boundaries&layout={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&device=Default

I dont want URL having this : &layout={00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}&device=Default

Config settings is :  
Rest is fine for me, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 3):

That URL is generated from sitecore. It's not IIS. This one you are getting is when the item doesn't have a layout set. You might also want to look at the not found url. You can set these urls to point to sitecore items in web.config:

Unfortunately, sitecore does not return a Not found status code, so it is better to create your own handler to read the Item and set the status code. See an example here from RUUD VAN FALIER: http://www.partechit.nl/en/blog/2012/11/return-404-status-code-when-itemnotfound-page-is-loaded

Basically, you append a processor after Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest and override RedirectOnItemNotFound and the RedirectOnLayoutNotFound as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add an additional section to `<system.webServer>` in your web.config.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

As well as setting `RequestErrors.UseServerSideRedirect` to true.

Reference: http://herskind.co.uk/blog/2012/03/sitecore-404-without-302

Answer (score 0):

Also you can add `existingResponse="PassThrough" along with erroMode`

Check detailed explanantion at: [IIS httpErrors](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, Surely I am going to try all the suggestion given above and will see which one is working finest with this case.

Right now I just implemented a code in my redirect module with every time of querystring appending on sitecore URL's

`Defined a baseURL using  Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);

```
                if (baseUrl.ToLower().Contains("?"))
                {
                    ReqUrl = baseUrl;
                    baseUrl = ReqUrl.Substring(0, ReqUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                    AppendedUrl = ReqUrl.Substring(baseUrl.Length);
                }

                string Qurl = Request.RawUrl;
                if (Qurl.ToLower().Contains("?"))
                {
                    Qurl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                    AppendedUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Qurl.Length);
                }

                if (Qurl.ToLower().EndsWith("/"))
                {
                    baseUrl = baseUrl + "/";
                }
                //Code for URLEncoding
                string fullPath = baseUrl + AppendedUrl;
                fullPath = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(fullPath);


                if (fullPath.ToLower().Contains("&layout"))
                {
                    fullPath = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("&layout"));
                }
                if (baseUrl.ToLower() != Qurl.ToLower())
                {
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(fullPath);
                }
            }      
        }`
```

so URL encoding and putting condition with types of querystring exist in website resolved my problem.

Thanks again for ideas, I am going to see alternate ways too from them.